# Detect output volume when volume is highest/lowest

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudiosession

So currently I'm using `AVAudioSession` to observe changes to the system's `outputVolume` and it works good. The pitfall is when the volume is at its absolute min/max, this property isn't modified and I have no way of detecting whether or not the user has messed with the volume controls. Is there another way of detecting the action of physically triggering the volume rocker?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe try avoid the volume goes to min/max by increase/decrease volume when it hits the min/max volume for further detection?

Comment: @EgistLi I'm not sure I follow your suggestion.

Comment: @StephenPaul did you figure this out?